# SQL Server : fire trigger on SELECT? (Calculated Column)

Tags: sql-server, triggers, calculated-columns

I need a column to be dynamic as such that a column `DaysToExpiration` is calculated based on the number of days between now and a date column `Expiration Date`.

My plan was to add a trigger that fires on a `SELECT`statement of the table.

1. Is this possible? How?
2. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: yes, a computed column would be a better choice IMO

Comment: A view on the table is the way to go, Creating a Trigger to stored the information somewhere else or even having a computed column to show the DaysToExpiration seems an over kill, some may even say violation of database normalization rules.

Comment: @M.Ali A view is a good idea. But I'm curious, why do you think it would be different than a computed column?, why do you think it's better?

Comment: @Lamak Why its better than a computed column , well not having an extra column that you don't really need is a good thing I guess, not having to maintain the extra column and you cant even create any indexes on it etc etc. I hope you get the point. A computed column is usually a good idea when the value needs to be computed at the point when it is inserted and it is persistent (persistent column will allow to create indexes as well on that column), something like `DaysToExpiration` (which needs to be calculated when it is being queried) a view is a much better option in my opinion

Comment: Response to **(1)**: **NO** - SQL Server does not have any triggers on `SELECT` ....

Answer (score 2):

You say "My plan was to add a Trigger that Fires on a SELECT statement of the table."

In that case why have a column at all, why not just select it in your final query?

```
Select DateDiff(day,getdate(),ExpirationDate) AS [DaysToExpiration]
```

If it must be persisted and stored in a column then you can make it a computed column as suggested in the comments.  Or you could have the table trigger on UPDATE/INSERT so when the ExpirationDate is inserted or updated it sets the DaysToExpiration column to the result of the provided code.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no provision of having trigger on SELECT operation. You can use stored procedure which takes parameters that are fetched from SELECT query and call this procedure after desired SELECT query.